# HTML attribute tag identifier?

Tags: html

If for example, I have a tag: `<a href="#">Ex1</a>`, I want to identify what that tag is doing there. Title,class & id attributes aren't options as I use class&id for CSS and title displays text when hovered. So, is there any attribute to do that? Thanks!

Comment: `I want to identify what that tag is doing there` - What do you mean?

Comment: Like for example <a href="#" someatts="this tag is here for">Ex1</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure what your asking, but are you trying to apply meta-data as an attribute?  If so, you can add more than one class (`class="one two three fourClasses"`), or use the [`data-`](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "data-[yourText]" as a cross-browser-safe attribute in any elements, and this often makes it nice to describe things because you can include more information in the custom data attribute value:

```
<a href="#" data-example="1">Ex1</a>
<a href="#" data-example="2">Ex2</a>
<a href="#" data-example="3">Ex3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `<!-- HTML comments -->` for annotations?

Comment: I need it for ajax, I can't retrieve comments, no?

Comment: You can, if you send them in the response, but you'd need to make sure you handled the encoding/decoding correctly.